# i have an flat file date format is mm-dd-yyyy and i need load it in to table. In table i have date column as yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

> How do it in expression transformation
>
> > Flat file
> > mm/dd/yyyy

table
yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 0):

EDIT, based on your comment

Output expression parameter, datatype datetime, set as:

TO_DATE( FILE_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY' )

FILE_DATE is your flat file source field, that you read as a string datatype.

Set target destination fields as datetime, which will accept the converted value as-is.

Comment: Both the flat file and table having date fields.

Comment: in flat file Date_field'mm/dd/yyyy'  now i need to change to table data type as 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Answer (score 0):

If file has data type as date, and target also has date type, then you can use this -

```
IIF (
IS_DATE(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(FILE_DATE,1,10)),'mm/dd/yyyy'), 
TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(FILE_DATE),1,10),'mm/dd/yyyy')
)
```

This will check if column is in proper date format or not, if not, then it will convert file_date to a date type else set it to null. Pls note, Database doesnt store date in any format, its just date.